# Pulseeffects not installing ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio

i was trying to install pulse effects on ubuntu 20.04 by this command  `sudo apt -y install pulseeffects` but it is giving an error saying unmet dependencies

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseeffects : Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the plugin first:

```
 sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

Then install pulseeffects again.

Comment: ```Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (= 1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1) but 1.16.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: it gives this error

Comment: Then try `sudo apt-get install -y libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0`

Comment: ```libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.16.3-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.``` its already installed

Comment: Please post the output of `apt list --upgradable`

Comment: ```Listing... Done
vivaldi-stable/stable 5.6.2867.50-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.6.2867.40-1]
N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.```

Comment: `apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` foreign package source.

Comment: ```gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
``` shows this

Comment: great i ask for the wrong package.  `sudo apt -f install  --reinstall libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0=1.16.2-2.1ubuntu1`

Comment: thankss it works now

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an alternative answer to help those who might arrive at this page having not yet chosen an installation method. I just found it trivially easy to get PulseEffects installed and working using the Synaptic package manager on my Ubuntu 22.04 system.

I first made sure that I didn't have any previous software upgrades waiting, stuck or held back. I then used Synaptic to search for PulseEffects. It found the package and its dependencies and optional plugins. I marked all plugins and the main package for installation. As I check marked each of those manually, a popup on most of them asked if I wanted to install required dependencies, to which I responded yes.

After all of that, I clicked the action button to have Synaptic install everything that had been marked. The installation went smoothly and immediately started working even with an already running audio stream to my headphones.